# Cannot Access .dbml Functions and Classes

Tags: c#, linq, dbml

I am creating a three tier website project. I am using `Linq to sql class` in my data-access-layer,all my sp's and tables are shown in `DataAccessLayerCodeFile.designer.cs` file,but when i make a instance of it in presentation layer,it successfully create the instance like this:

```
DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayerCodeFileDataContext dbInstance = new DataAccessLayer.DataAccessLayerCodeFileDataContext();
```

But when i want to used dbInstance, it is not showing in intellisense and not showing classes and functions (sp's).i-e i want to call sp's from **dbInstance.**, but i can't access it?Kindly guide me what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a **Web site project**, you must put the data classes in the project's `App_Code` folder or in a sub-folder of `App_Code`. If you include the data classes in a sub-folder of `App_Code`, the name of the sub-folder will be used as the namespace for the classes. In that case, you must provide that namespace when you connect to the data classes.While at the same time i have created a sample **web application project**, it does not allow me to do the same stuff,as far i research, link mention below explicitly stated the same procedure for **web application project**, but on reality it does not support to access the instance.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb907587(v=vs.100).aspx][1]